# Int object not iterable

Tags: python

I have been studying about the list comprehension. So I have decided to code something with a `for` loop which looks like

```
babe = 122132323
b = [n for n in babe]
print b
```

When I run the above code it gives me error like  `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

I have researched about these similar errors but I don't know what wrong with my code. It would be really appreciated if anyone tell me how can I overcome this error and make the code work.

Comment: That means `122132323` is not iterable! you cannot iterate a number.

Comment: you have a single object, i.e a single identity. You cannot iterate through it.

Comment: Did you mean "122132323" (or a list) rather than just an int?

Comment: @ThePredator can you tell me an example of an iterating value

Answer (score 1):

`int` variables are not `sequences` and neither `iterable`. you have to make it string.

```
In [60]: babe = '122132323'

In [61]: b = [n for n in babe] #this pick every item from left and store it in `n` then return n.

In [62]: b
Out[62]: ['1', '2', '2', '1', '3', '2', '3', '2', '3']
```

or simple use `list` builtin-function.

```
[63]: list(babe)
Out[63]: ['1', '2', '2', '1', '3', '2', '3', '2', '3']
```

Comment: or just use `list(babe)`. And perhaps a `str()` call on `babe` first if it is an integer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for considering my answer. i updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate on an integer value, you need `n for n in range (babe)`.  That tells Python to use the numbers from zero to `babe-1` as loop counter values.  Assuming you want to have an actual number, of course...

Comment: Please expand by editing your answer. Why would that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the object you have is not iterable is because **it is not a string**. It is a single number, **i.e an integer**.

If you on the other hand, had a string, say

```
babe = '122132323'
b = [n for n in babe]
print b
```

It will print

```
['1', '2', '2', '1', '3', '2', '3', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

What values of `n` are you looking for?

`1`, `2`, `2`, `1`, `3`, `2`, `3`, `2`, `3`

or

`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `...`, `122132323`?

For the first you need

```
[n for n in '122132323']
```

and for the second you need

```
n for n in range(babe)]
```

(or just `list(range(babe))`.